# Removing a child node from XmlNode

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am using `XPath` to select a report node. Now what I want to know here is how can I remove that node from the document without knowing which node's children they are?

I tried calling `.RemoveChild` and it throws this error :

> The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

This is my code for deleting a node :

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//report");
doc.RemoveChild(node);
```

Comment: I know you're probably aware of this, but that XPath will find a "report" element *anywhere* in the document. You know your schema better than I do, but "//" XPath queries always make me feel uneasy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get know the parent node:

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

*Please note that the `node.ParentNode` can be `null`.*